# The Css And Js Files Not Loaded On Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem: the css and js files not loaded, but It's showed on source code.

I'm including it on `functions.php` file just like below code.
The source page: http://jalid-wp.co.nf

Please any help for this problem.

```
function load_scripts() {
    // CSS Files
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/main.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'responsive', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/responsive.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'animate', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/animate.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'ionicons-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/ionicons.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-carousel-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'owl-theme-default-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/owl.theme.default.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'pe-icons-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/pe-icons.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'material-icons', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/material-icons.css' );
    // Colors
    wp_enqueue_style( 'color', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/colors/default.css' );
    // JS Files
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.min.js', array(), '3.2.1', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl-carousel-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/owl.carousel.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slideNav', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/slideNav.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/main.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'wow-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/wow.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootbox-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootbox.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'isotope-min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/isotope.min.js', array(), 'null', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_scripts' );
```

Comment: first of all, don't use trivial function names like `load_scripts`. what do you mean with `but It's showed on source code`? can you provide more details?

Comment: @Kos ! Thanks you, The problem is solved ! it's just a f***** code on .htaccess file ! I remove it and the files work <3

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have some sort of redirect on your site.
No matter what page you try to visit it always redirects to the main page.

I believe this is why the CSS and JS are not working because the web server just keeps redirecting all URL's to the main page.

I suggest looking at your .htaccess for any url rewrites and remove them. Once .htaccess is cleaned up, you can then verify if everything loads and displays properly.

Once working, you can research or post a question around fixing your .htaccess file, to redirect as you like.

Comment: <3 Thanks you a lot <3 I remove a code on .htaccess file and all work <3 Thanks you <3